One element orbit under modular matrix congruence action
Let G a sub-group of GL(n,2) (nonsingular matrices over GF(2)) and M any matrix (singular or nosingular) of type n by n of entries in the Galois Field of two elements GF(2)= {0,1}, such that for any matrix A in G we have
A.M.A^T = M
where A^T is the transpose of A. How to shoose the group G to ensure M=0 (a null matrix n by n). Note that all operations in this question must be performed mod 2.

What surprises me in this question is that almost in all non-trivial choices of G we have M a zero matrix.
